# I need to modify the tkinter triple button click counter code

Tags: python, tkinter, button

Okay, I made a little tkinter program that basically counts how many times the button was clicked and implemented the triple button module so that it counts every third click, but I wanted to change it up so that the button instead of saying "Click me!", displays the number of clicks itself.

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Main():

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.count = 0

        frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        frame.pack()
        
        label = tk.Label(root, text="Super click counter!", font=('Arial', 18))
        label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        btn = tk.Button(frame, text ='Click me!')
        btn.pack()
        btn.bind('<Triple-Button>', self.click)

        self.label = tk.Label(frame, text = 'The button was clicked 0 times.')
        self.label.pack()

    def click(self, event):
        self.count += 1
        self.label.config(text=f'The button was clicked {self.count} times.')
        
if __name__=="__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.geometry("300x150")
    root.title("A serious video game.")
    Main(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is working. Nothing wrong. Just click button faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we add the `btn` property by using `self.btn =`  then we change the text inside it when the button is clicked 3 times using `self.btn.config(text=self.count.__str__())`

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Main():

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.count = 0

        frame = tk.Frame(self.root)
        frame.pack()
        
        label = tk.Label(root, text="Super click counter!", font=('Arial', 18))
        label.pack(padx=20, pady=20)

        self.btn = tk.Button(frame, text ='Click me!')
        self.btn.pack()
        self.btn.bind('<Triple-Button>', self.click)

        self.label = tk.Label(frame, text = 'The button was clicked 0 times.')
        self.label.pack()

    def click(self, event):
        self.count += 1
        self.label.config(text=f'The button was clicked {self.count} times.')
        self.btn.config(text=self.count.__str__())
```